# How to implement LaunchDarkly on Flutter Web?

Tags: javascript, flutter, launchdarkly

The package https://pub.dev/packages/launchdarkly_flutter_client_sdk only has support for Android and IOS. I am trying to use the JavaScript SDK, but so far I have not been able to make it work.